# Android Performance : Adding view programmatically vs setting view to GONE/VISIBLE

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view

I'm working in a project that requires to inflate a simple tutorial View when the user opens the app for the first time. I'm trying to do it "the right way", and I'm wondering about performance issue.

Currently, I have in my layout a view sets to `android:visibility="GONE"`, which I change to `VISIBLE` depending on a SharedPreference. This allows me to let the user learn how the app works on first launches.

What I'm wondering is what it implies when the view is rendered in my Fragment. My guess is that the view will be uselessly inflated, even if its visibility is set to `GONE`.

Now, I'm thinking about an alternative: what if I would only add my View on first launches, but programmatically, in my Fragment's `onCreateView`. That should allow the view not to be inflated on later launches, but wouldn't inflating the view programmatically implies bad performance on first launches?

Comment: Not sure about performance comparison. But if its really something like tutorial on first run, then give [Showcase View](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) a try :)

Comment: @PurpleDroid Well, I'm actually showing it as a `CardView` right now. It's just a FYI for first time user, not really a tutorial! :-)

Comment: @MagicMicky : Sorry but I have to ask "What have you tried?". It's very easy to use something like DDMS to track the progress of an app using logcat. Why don't you just try the different approaches yourself and see what happens?

Comment: @Squonk Well, I haven't really had the chance to play with android debug tools and DDMS yet. I figured someone might know how the platform would really work, but you're right, I should definitely try it out. I'll try to do this right now, I'll keep this thread updated when I find something valuable. `TraceView` might actually do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, to answer my own question I used the DDMS tool `TraceView` to monitor the calls from my fragment `onAttach` until its `onResume`. It let me see which implementation are the less efficient.

To do the test, I had a simple `RelativeLayout` with a `FrameLayout` inside it (shown all the time). I used a custom layout to add each time, either programmatically or with a visibility of GONE on my layout file. The custom layout was composed of a RelativeLayout with 4 childs (an ImageView, a TextView, a View, and a Button).

My `onCreateView` was the following, allowing the app to inflate the right layout based on two `static final boolean` constants to change the layouts.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout root;
    if(INFLATE_PROGRAMMATICALY) {
        root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_prgmcly, container, false);
        if(SHOULD_FYI_VIEW_BE_SHOWN) {
            View tutoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_view, root, false);
            root.addView(tutoView);
        }
    } else {
        root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_gone,container,false);
        if(SHOULD_FYI_VIEW_BE_SHOWN) {
            View tutoView = root.findViewById(R.id.RL_inner_view);
            tutoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

This lead to the following results:

**When the optional layout in inflated**

*`SHOULD_FYI_VIEW_BE_SHOWN=true`*

The maximum "real time estimate" given by the TraceView are of **75ms** when there is just a view to change from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`, but of **110ms** when we need to instantiate the `inner_view`.

**When the optional layout isn't inflated**
*`SHOULD_FYI_VIEW_BE_SHOWN=false`*

In this case, the maximum real time estimate given by TraceView are of **102ms** for the inflation of the `GONE` view, versus **39ms** when the view inflated doesn't have the `GONE` view.

So, for the performance gain when the views doesn't need to be inflated, I'd say that the best solution is **to inflate your view programmatically if you only need to show it a few time**.

*You can find the test project on a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MagicMicky/3868f9ea762e4ad95884)*

Answer (score 7):

I think you are reinventing a wheel. For this scenario is already existing tool in Android xml layouts. It is called ViewStub. You can read more here: [Loading ondemand](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think I just randomly stumbled over the answer of your performance question.

From the [Animation Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html):

> For the view that is being faded in, set its visibility to GONE. This
> prevents the view from taking up layout space and **omits it from layout**
> **calculations, speeding up processing.**

This would mean performance is not compromised as long as you don't set `android:visibility` to anything else than `GONE`.